# Linq: Except on two different types of dictionaries

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-objects

i have 2 different types of dictionaries `Dictionary<int, Fooclass> oldDic` and `Dictionary<int, string> barList newDic` . Now i need to compare values in both dictionaries. for Example key can be in

- oldDic : 1,2,3
- newDic : 1,2,3,4
- Expected Output  : 4

Now i need to compare both dictionaries on basis of their keys 
any help would be appreciated.

Edit :
Output should be like second dictionary(newDic) but this will contain some value of 2nd dictionary's(oldDic). For example

1,"fooString" Where fooString is some value in Fooclass's someproperty....
For more clarity see this which doesn't worked for me

```
var addedList = from list1 in baseListDic
join list2 in trackerlist on list1.Key equals list2.Key
 select new { key = list1.Key, value = list1.Value._lead };
```

here baseListDic is oldDic and trackerlist is newDic....
Let me know if i'm still not clear...

Comment: IEnumerable<int> result = newDic.Keys.Except(oldDic.Keys)

Comment: @huMptyduMpty well i have tried this but this one gives me output only 4. But i need some value from fooClass also...see my new edit in above post..

Comment: Your new edit doesn't seem to agree with your original example. in your original you are returning the key that is in newdic but not old dic but in your second example you seem to be returning values in olddic that have keys in newdic? Perhaps create a small program with some sample dictionaries that demonstrates what you want? Nobody will ever object to you giving them some code they can run easily... :)

Comment: @Chris well, yes you are right...according to first example my requirement seems diff...but in my new edit...i have written something which matches similar keys in both dictionaries like inner join and it's a failed code so i just posted this for an example what my output should be....

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It would be easier to just create a new dictionary based on the new dictionary ignoring items that have the same key in the old dictionary.

```
var result = newDic
    .Where(kvp => !oldDic.ContainsKey(kvp.Key))
    .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
```

Answer (score 7):

Note: Despite your question saying "i need to compare **values** in both dictionaries" (emphasis mine) your example seems to be demonstrating just comparison of keys so I've gone with that. If it is values you need to compare you might want to give an example of what you mean and if they are easily convertible or comparable...

If you are only actually comparing the keys then you can just use the `.Keys` property of the dictionary which returns an `IEnumerable<TKey>` that you can do your linq on...

eg:

```
var expectedOutput = newDic.Keys.Except(oldDic.Keys);
```

This does rely on the key being the same type but this goes without saying if you are comparing. Of course, there is nothing stopping you from converting their types first if you do wnat to do this with different types.

Also if you wanted to then get the values in one of the dictionaries you could do something like:

```
var newDicValues = expectedoutput.Select(x=>newDic[x]);
```

Or, you know, do any other linqy stuff you feel like. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this to get the difference between two different list: If they have any common property.

```
 var differentItems = List<Type1>.Select(d => d.Name)
                        .Except(List<Type2>.Select(d => d.Name));
```

Answer (score 0):

If understood correctly, try something like this

if you have a separate dictionary moething like this `Dictionary<int, Fooclass> FinalDict`

```
            IEnumerable<int> list = OldDic.Keys.Except(NewDic.Keys);
            foreach (var x in list)
            {
                var value =new MyClass();
                OldDic.TryGetValue(x,out value );
                FinalDict.Add(x,value);
            }
```

So in the Dictionary called ***FinalDict*** will have the key and related ***Fooclass***

Hope this helps

Comment: since all the x came from oldDic you shouldn't need to use TryGetvalue... In fact I'd have thought that this would be simpler as `OldDic.Where(x=> !NewDic.ContainsKey(x.Key)).ToDictionary(x=>x.Key, x=>x.Value)`